# How can you change the highlighted text color for a WPF TextBox?

Tags: wpf, textbox, resources, styles, highlight

The WPF `TextBox` natively makes use of the System Highlight color for painting the background of selected text.  I would like to override this and make it consistent since it varies by OS/user theme.

For `ListBoxItem`s, there is a [neat trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/08/31/specifying-the-selection-color-content-alignment-and-background-color-for-items-in-a-listbox.aspx) (see below) where you can override the resource key for the `HighlightBrushKey` to customize the System Highlight color in a focused setting:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                         Color="LightGreen"/>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

The same trick does not work for the `TextBox` unfortunately.  Does anyone have any other ideas, besides "override the `ControlTemplate`"?

[NOTE: This behavior appears to be added to WPF 4.](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2009/10/27/new-wpf-features-caretbrush-selectionbrush.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Steve mentioned : [NOTE: This behavior appears to be added to WPF 4.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/new-wpf-features-caretbrushselectionbrush)

I bumped into the same problem.

As Dr.WPF says

> "It is entirely impossible in the
> current .NET releases (3.0 & 3.5
> beta).  The control is hardcoded to
> use the system setting... it doesn't
> look at the control template at all."

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bbffa6e3-2745-4e72-80d0-9cdedeb69f7f/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, especially that the ControlTemplate is also ignored as I probably would have tried that failing all else.

Comment: First link in answer is dead - *"404 | Page not found"*.

Answer (score 11):

Since .NET 4, [`TextBoxBase.SelectionBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionbrush.aspx)

> You can specify the brush that highlights selected text by setting the SelectionBrush and SelectionOpacity properties. The SelectionOpacity property specifies the opacity of the SelectionBrush.

eg.

```
<TextBox SelectionBrush="Red" SelectionOpacity="0.5"
         Foreground="Blue" CaretBrush="Blue">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows 8.1 .Net 4.6.1 tested solution to customize the `SelectionBrush` of each `TextBox` in the app:

```
/// Constructor in App.xaml.cs
public App() : base()
{
    // Register an additional SelectionChanged handler for appwide each TextBox
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.SelectionChangedEvent, RoutedEventHandler(_textBox_selectionChanged));
}

private void _textBox_selectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Customize background color of selected text
    (sender as TextBox).SelectionBrush = Brushes.MediumOrchid;

    // Customize opacity of background color
    (sender as TextBox).SelectionOpacity = 0.5;
}
```

If you want to include `RichTextBox` replace type name `TextBox` 4 times by `TextBoxBase`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Style for the TextBox and write a Setter for the background. The TextBox style should be a default one so that any TextBox which comes under the visual tree will get the changed TextBox

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
```

Comment: That would change the background color of the entire text box, what I was looking for is how to change the background for the highlighted portion only.  Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
     <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="OrangeRed"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
```

Comment: IsHighlighted is not a property on TextBox, what element would you use that trigger on?

Comment: I looked again and confirmed, that is not a property on TextBox.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  

I suspect you are using some other type of control, or a custom derived version of TextBox.

Comment: The example above is for a ListBox.

Comment: Ok, this question was about a TextBox.  ListBox was given as an example where there was already a workaround available.