# How do I set ComboBox's Textbox SelectionBrush to a different color?

Tags: wpf, combobox, textbox

There was already a post on this but appeared there was no resolution.  Perhaps it was before the `SelectionBrush` property was exposed for the `TextBox`.

I have a `Style` for the `TextBox` in my resources that works correctly (the selected text is not the default System color but a color I have chosen).  I would assume the `TextBox` component of my custom `ComboBox` template would use that `TextBox` `Style` but the selected text in the `ComboBox` `TextBox` is still blue.

Since I know I can control the selected text color of a `TextBox`, how do I control it in my `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`?  I have image and code exaqmples but this forum will not let me post them since this is my first time.

Comment: Try this: [How to customize selection brush for each TextBox in your app](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34381625/3135228)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code, it solve your problem

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="ramesh test" Margin="67,12,184,240" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="testCombo" Margin="67,48,184,204">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBox  Text="mytext" Width="100" Height="50" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ComboBox `HighlightBrushKey` color

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,0,0,148">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work in a resource dictionary.